# Is the total space of the frame bundle of a smooth manifold $M$ always spin?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, principal-bundles, spin-geometry

I seem to remember reading in Kobayashi that the total space of a frame bundle is always parallelizable. If I'm remembering this correctly then the total space of the frame bundle $FM$ is always spin, for arbitrary $M$.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, any parallelizable manifold is in particular spin.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan   Thanks, I just wasn't sure if  I was remembering the parallelizability of frame bundles accurately I'll try and look it up